# use 2 mat paginators in same component in angular for different data source

Tags: html, angular

I have 2 tables...trying to use 2 mat paginators.

TS file:

```
@ViewChild('TableOnePaginator') tableOnePaginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('TableTwoPaginator') tableTwoPaginator: MatPaginator;

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(this.elements);
dataSource1 = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement1>(this.elements1);

constructor(private service:Service) {
  this.service.getlaneptedata().then(response=>{
    this.elements=response;
    this.dataSource= new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(this.elements);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.tableOnePaginator;})
}

popUp(row){
   this.service.getlanepte(row.zip3).then(response=>{
    this.elements1=response;
     this.dataSource1= new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement1>(this.elements1);
     this.dataSource1.paginator = this.tableTwoPaginator;})
}
```

when you click on any row in first table popUp(row) method calls.

HTML file:

First table:

```
<mat-paginator #TableOnePaginator="matPaginator" [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Second Table:

```
<mat-paginator #TableTwoPaginator="matPaginator" [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Second table paginator is not working....

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try assing the paginators `this.dataSource1.paginator = this.tableTwoPaginator;` in ngAfterViewInit

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.TableOnePaginator;
  this.dataSource1.paginator = this.tableTwoPaginator;
}
```

or use `@ViewChild('TableOnePaginator',{static:true})`.

```
@ViewChild('TableOnePaginator',{static:true}
@ViewChild('tableTwoPaginator',{static:true}
```

If your paginator is not visible when asign the paginator, enclosed the instruction between setTimeout() to give Angular time to show it.

```
popUp(row){
   this.service.getlanepte(row.zip3).then(response=>{
    this.elements1=response;
     this.dataSource1= new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement1>(this.elements1);
     setTimeout(()=>{
       this.dataSource1.paginator = this.tableTwoPaginator;
     })
   })
}
```