# How to catch mat table paginator (initialized) observable

Tags: angular, paginator

from the material Paginator API https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api
there is  initialized: Observable - Stream that emits once during the directive/component's ngOnInit.
I need to know how to use this directive to catch when Paginator initialized, since no examples available for it, because I have many paginators in one component and can't give them the # id.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular the "id" it's not important. if you has a paginator indide a *ngFor use a template reference variables (yes, the #what-ever) and use ViewChildren to get it, is you only has two or more table check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71070307/angular-mat-paginator-multiple-tables-in-a-component/71072872#71072872).

If you want to use the property `initialized`it's only get the MatPaginator using ViewChild or ViewChildren  and make, e.g.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator,{static:true}) paginator:MatPaginator

ngOnInit()
{
   this.paginator.initialize.subscribe(_=>{
     console.log("initialized")
   }
}
```