# mat-paginator is not working for two tables in a single component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to implement mat-paginator and mat-sort in two tables that are present in the same component. The method I have implemented is not working on both the table. mat-paginator and sort is working only in the first table. How can I make it work for both?

Table1-

```
<table matSort mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
                  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

                  <!-- Position Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="SNo">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      S.No.
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
                      {{ i + 1 }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="contactPerson">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      Contact Person
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.contactPerson }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="primaryEmailId">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      Primary Email
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.primaryEmailId }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="secondaryEmailId">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      Secondary Email
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.secondaryEmailId }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="primaryMobileNo">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      Primary Mobile
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.primaryMobileNo }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="secondaryMobileNo">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      Secondary Email
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.secondaryMobileNo }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      Status
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.status ? "Active" : "Not Active" }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-center">
                      Actions
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      <div
                        style="
                          display: flex;
                          gap: 10px;
                          justify-content: center;
                        "
                      >
                        <mat-icon
                          routerLink="/company/updateBranchContact"
                          [queryParams]="{
                            branchId: element.companyBranchId,
                            branchContactId: element.id
                          }"
                          class="edit-icon"
                          matTooltip="Update Company"
                          >edit</mat-icon
                        >

                        <mat-icon
                          (click)="deleteBranchContact(element.id)"
                          class="delete-icon"
                          matTooltip="Delete Company"
                          >delete</mat-icon
                        >
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumn"></tr>
                  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumn"></tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <mat-paginator
                [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15, 20]"
                showFirstLastButtons
              ></mat-paginator>
```

table2-

```
<table matSort mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource1">
                  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

                  <!-- Position Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="SNo">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      S.No.
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
                      {{ i + 1 }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="companyPanNo">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      Pan No.
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.companyPanNo }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="companyCinNo">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                     CIN No.
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.companyCinNo }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="companyPfNo">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      PF No.
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.companyPfNo }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="companyEsiNo">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      ESI No.
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.companyEsiNo }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="companyTanNo">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      Tan No.
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.companyTanNo }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="companyTdsCircle">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      TDS Circle No.
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.companyTdsCircle }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="companyAoCode">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      AO Code
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.companyAoCode }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                    <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                      Status
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      {{ element.status ? "Active" : "Not Active" }}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-center">
                      Actions
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                      <div
                        style="
                          display: flex;
                          gap: 10px;
                          justify-content: center;
                        "
                      >
                        <mat-icon
                          routerLink=""
                          [queryParams]="{
                            branchId: element.companyBranchId,
                            branchContactId: element.id
                          }"
                          class="edit-icon"
                          matTooltip="Update Company"
                          >edit</mat-icon
                        >

                        <mat-icon
                          (click)="deleteBranchStatutory(element.id)"
                          class="delete-icon"
                          matTooltip="Delete Company"
                          >delete</mat-icon
                        >
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumn1"></tr>
                  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumn1"></tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <mat-paginator
                [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 4, 8, 10]"
                showFirstLastButtons
              ></mat-paginator>
```

.ts file -

```
public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  public dataSource1 = new MatTableDataSource();

  public displayColumn: string[] = [
    'SNo',
    'contactPerson',
    'primaryEmailId',
    'secondaryEmailId',
    'primaryMobileNo',
    'secondaryMobileNo',
    'status',
    'action',
  ];

  public displayColumn1: string[] = [
    'SNo',
    'companyPanNo',
    'companyCinNo',
    'companyPfNo',
    'companyEsiNo',
    'companyTanNo',
    'companyTdsCircle',
    'companyAoCode',
    'status',
    'action',
  ];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getBranchContact();
    this.getBranchStatutory();
  }
getBranchContact = () => {
    this.reposotory
      .getBranchContact(
        `api/CompanyBranch/CompanyContactListByCompanyBranch?CompanyBranchId=${this.companyBranchId}`
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('contact data:', data);
        this.branchContact = data;
        this.dataSource.data = data;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
  };
  filterChange(data: Event) {
    const value = (data.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = value;
  }
 getBranchStatutory() {
    this.reposotory
      .getStatutory(`api/CompanyStatutoryIdentity/CompanyStatutoryList`)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('Statutory', data);
        this.dataSource1.data = data;
        this.dataSource1.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource1.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }

  filterChange1(data: Event) {
    const value = (data.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource1.filter = value;
  }
```

I tried implementing it using different datasource but its not working.

Comment: a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71070307/angular-mat-paginator-multiple-tables-in-a-component